# In setting viewset, I got an error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm learning DRF and feel confused a little now.
I set up `QuestionView` and `QuestionSerializer` like this.

**views.py**

```
class QuestionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    queryset = models.Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(models.Question.objects.all())
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Question
        fields= ("question_text", "owner", "pub_date")
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('profile', cebula_views.SettingView)
router.register('question', cebula_views.QuestionView.as_view({
    'get':'list',

}), 'userpage-question')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

> File "C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\businessproject\urls.py", line 34, in
>   
>       url(r'^', include(router.urls)),   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py",
>   line 101, in urls
>       self._urls = self.get_urls()   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py",
>   line 363, in get_urls
>       urls = super(DefaultRouter, self).get_urls()   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py",
>   line 261, in get_urls
>       routes = self.get_routes(viewset)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py",
>   line 176, in get_routes
>       extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions() AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

In my opinion, It is that I should write `get_extra_actions` method in `QuestionView` class, If so, how I write that? like this?

```
def get_extra_actions() : 
    return  ???
```

If not, what is the problem?

**[Edit]**

when I erase .as_view() at the url part and write like `router.register('question', cebula_views.QuestionView, 'userpage-question')`

the error is

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x00000283172D3D08> Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 225, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 120, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 364, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 351, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 73, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 13, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 23, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 397, in check
>       for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 36, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 536, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 36, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 529, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\businessproject\urls.py", line 31, in 
>       url(r'^cebula/',include('cebula.urls',namespace='cebula')),   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py",
>   line 34, in include
>       urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula3\cebula\urls.py", line 15, in 
>       url(r'^question/$',views.QuestionView.as_view(),name='question'),   File
>   "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py",
>   line 68, in as_view
>       raise TypeError("The `actions` argument must be provided when " TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling
>   `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why, but I couldn't create a route (with an .as_view()) using routers as well. But, when i tried to create the route directly in urlpatterns it worked for me.

So, it would be something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('question', cebula_views.QuestionView.as_view({
         'get':'list',
         }), 'userpage-question'),
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use **`.as_view()`** method while registering the viewset in *routers*

So, it should be

```
router.register('question', cebula_views.QuestionView, 'userpage-question')
```

instead of

```
router.register('question', cebula_views.QuestionView.as_view({
    'get':'list',

}), 'userpage-question')
```

Comment: I also want to do that but when I write like `router.register('question', cebula_views.QuestionView, 'userpage-question')` the error is > url(r'^question/$',views.QuestionView.as_view(),name='question'),
  File "C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 68, in as_view
    raise TypeError("The `actions` argument must be provided when "
TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`

Comment: pls add complete traceback to question portion by editing it

Answer (score 2):

use this URL format.

```
    from django.urls import path
    from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
    from .views import QuestionView

    urlpatterns = [
     path('QuestionView/', QuestionView),
    ]

    urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```