# Django Rest API: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django

I try to make an endpoint to add new records in db with a post request but I receive this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

I'm using VS Code.

my views.py

```
class newUser(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def createUser(self, request):
        name: request.POST['name']  
        phone: request.POST['phone']
        email: request.POST['email']
        
        newUser = User(name=name, phone=phone, email=email)
        User.save()
        return newUser
```

my routes

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user',UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'createuser',newUser, basename='createuser')
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     # path('api/users/', UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Stack trace:

```
"C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\Documents\VS_projects\python\gestionale\gestionale\urls.py", line 30, in <module>
    urlpatterns += router.urls
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 77, in urls
    self._urls = self.get_urls()
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 338, in get_urls
    urls = super().get_urls()
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 236, in get_urls
    routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
  File "C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 152, in get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()      
AttributeError: type object 'newUser' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

Comment: without as_view is the same, I receive 404 not found

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM no I'm sorry without as_view I receive 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

What code editor are you using? Have you downloaded the Django module?
if not check these things:

1. pip is up to date by using: `pip -V`
2. If it is not up to date update it using: pip3 install --upgrade pip
3. then install Django by using: python -m pip install django

Comment: this not solved my problem, I've shared the full stacktrace, I'm using vs code

Comment: have you looked at this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488977/in-setting-viewset-i-got-an-error-attributeerror-function-object-has-no-attr?rq=1

Comment: The answer does not relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

May be a syntax error in views.py. Note there was ":" instead of "=" for variable definitions

views.py

```
class newUser(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def createUser(self, request):
        name = request.POST['name']  
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        email = request.POST['email']
    
        newUser = User(name=name, phone=phone, email=email)
        User.save()
        return newUser
```

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider accepting it or upvoting. Thank you